# What's the appropriate way to replace my wrong design?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a question about nuxt.js project,

as we know the nuxt.js generate the routes automatically.

I have a page structure like this:

[image]

In the header there is navigator in it, I want use it to switch pages(switch the main body's content).

but the nuxt.js do not like vue-router have `<router-view/>`

```
<route-link></route-link>
<router-view/>
```

it only has

```
<nuxt-link></nuxt-link>
```

So I write code structure like this:

```
<template>
  <div >

    <Header></Header>   <!-- the main body written in the Header -->

    <Footer></Footer>

  </div>
</template>
```

the Header component:

```
    <navigator-component></navigator-component>

    <div>
      <Home v-show="$store.state.page_name == 'home' "></Home>
      <Search v-show="$store.state.page_name == 'search' "></Search>
      <Aboutus v-show="$store.state.page_name == 'about_us' "></Aboutus>
      <Contactus v-show="$store.state.page_name == 'contact_us' "> 
      </Contactus>
    </div>
```

but there is a problem, the URL will not switch, it will stay in the root URL.

So, what's the appropriate way to solve my problem? how to design the 
code structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuxt has a "router-view". It is just: `<nuxt />`.

The way to go here, is to use layouts.

There is a `default` file in the layouts directory. Every page has this layout by default.

You can simply write in this default layout file your page structure.

For example:

```
<template>
  <Header />
  <nuxt />
  <Footer />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Header from '..';
import Footer from '..';

export default {
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer,
  },
};
</script>
```